Probability of rolling n of a kind or greater in k dice rolls
I was bored in high school recently and wanted to find the probabilities of different situations in the game Liar's Dice, but I couldn't figure out a way to calculate the probability of rolling $n$ of a kind or more on $6$-sided dice, not dependent on the face, from some number of dice:

An example to help clarify is that it would be $1/6$ for $2$ dice and $2$ of a kind, and a $100\ \%$ chance of $1$ of a kind for any number of $\mbox{dice}\ > 0$.
I was hoping that someone could help me figure out how to find this.

Sorry about anything that's unclear, I'm new to $\tt Stack\ Exchange$, and don't have much practice describing mathematical ideas.

Your question isn't clear.  Are you fixing a value, $6$ say, and asking for the probability that you throw at least $n$ $6's$ out of $k$ tosses or are you asking for the probability that you throw at least $n$ of some value out of $k$ tosses?

@abomasnow  Agreed on all three  points.

Please edit your post for clarity.  Note that it would help if we knew, say, that $n>\frac k2$.  In that case, having $n$ of one sort would preclude having $n$ of any other which simplifies the computation.
